# HTML import to wordpress, set publish date to match filename

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress, import

I have a collection of 16,000 html files that I'm uploading to wordpress. I'm using HTML import 2. The date for the articles is located in two spots, neither of which can be detected by the plugin:

1.) each file is titled mmddyyxxxxxxx.htm
2.) the date exists in the same format in a paragraph at the bottom of the page, but surrounded by varying text. format: (yyyy, mm, dd)

and ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution here would be to use the "**set timestamps to last time the file was modified.**" option while importing.  Since the filenames have stamps in their dates, you can write a simple script to make the timestamps match. This can be done in bash, or PHP with the `touch()` function.

You may need to break up your files in usable groups, since `glob()` has a limit, but, here's a simple example to accomplish this:

```
<?php
# change mod+access times based on filenames
$files = glob("myfiles/*.htm");
foreach( $files as $file ) {
    $temp = pathinfo( $file );      // may have relative path in it
    $name = $temp['filename'];      // just "mmddyyxxxxxxx" at this point

    // assuming date format in filenames are fixed-lengths, you can rebuild
    // timestamp to yyyy-mm-dd format with this:
    $date = sprintf("20%s-%s-%s",   // cheap trick to start years with 20
        substr( $name, 4, 2 ),
        substr( $name, 2, 2 ),
        substr( $name, 0, 2 )
    );
    $stamp = strtotime( $name );    // timestamp

    touch( $file, $stamp, $stamp ); // sets both mod + access time
}
?>
```

In case that your date format in the filename isn't fixed, you may need to get more creative.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. I'm so close now. The only problem is, all my timestamps were changed to January 1st, 1970. When I echo $stamp I get the mmyydd format (091813) which leads me to believe my operating system requires a different format for the stamp? I'm not sure if operating systems do stamps differently but I will look into this. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, believe the issue was with the date format in filenames; `strtotime()` doesn't like 091813, but rebuilding it as 2013-09-18 will work. On that note, if all the entries are older than 2000, you're good to go. Elsewise, you may need to alter that '20'.

Comment: Erm, meant newer, not older. You get the idea ;)

Comment: I deem this issue 100% solved. You, sir, represent the reason this site is so great.

Comment: A few small corrections to anyone who might use this in their projects (the author wrote this fast, which I do appreciate.) In the above code the second and third substr in the $date argument should be switched in order for the timestamp to properly change. Also, the $stamp argument should be $stamp = strotime( $date ). A big thanks to pp19dd for his quick and eloquent work.